# How to use featrure New UI or new watchlist on ScadaLTS like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EasfrHZqPo

Tags: scadalts

How to use featrure New UI or new watchlist on ScadaLTS  like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EasfrHZqPo

i was installed scadalts version 0.0.9

Comment: Try to run from the docker https://github.com/SCADA-LTS/Scada-LTS/wiki/Run-ScadaLTS-on-docker---instruction
A new UI on docker is added